# Could not autowire JobLauncherTestUtils

Tags: spring, junit, spring-batch

I am attempting to test a simple spring batch application.

Using the Spring Batch documentation as a guide ([found here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting)), I have created the following test class:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@SpringBatchTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BatchConfig.class)
class BatchConfigTest {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    void userStep() {
        assertNotNull(jobLauncherTestUtils, "jobLauncherTestUtils should not be null");
    }
}
```

According to docs `@SpringBatchTest` should inject the `JobLaucherTestUtils` bean. However, when I run the test, the assertion fails. I have also tried defining the bean in an inner configuration class and had the same result:

```
    static class TestConfiguration {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("userJob")
        private Job userJob;

        @Bean
        public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
            JobLauncherTestUtils utils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
            utils.setJob(userJob);
            return utils;
        }
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing? The full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/matthewgreene/spring-batch-demo/tree/master).

Comment: Can you specify which version of Spring Batch and Junit you are using?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I am using Spring Batch v4.2.0 and JUnit 5

Comment: ok thanks. Let me check and get back to you asap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am using Spring Batch v4.2.0 and JUnit 5

You are using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` which is for JUnit 4. You need to use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` for JUnit 5 tests:

```
@SpringBatchTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BatchConfig.class)
class BatchConfigTest {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for point that out. I have updated the code, but I'm still unable to autowire   the `jobLauncherTestUtils` bean. The error I see is `Could not autowire. No beans of 'JobLauncherTestUtils' type found.`

Comment: works as expected on my side, here is a minimal complete example: https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-sandbox/tree/master/so59726807

Comment: Thank you for that example. It seems the primary issue is that I do not have a datasource bean defined for testing. Defining the datasource in a testing specific configuration class and including it in the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation seems to have done the trick. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The example link didn't work, searching github, I found the correct link:  https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/issues/so59726807

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem with Spring Batch 4.1.3 and JUnit 4.12.

Replacing `@SpringBatchTest` with `@SpringBootTest` solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing the same error in IntelliJ and spent ages looking into why before I ran the test. It was being injected just fine, IntelliJ was incorrectly telling me the bean wasn't there.

:facepalm:

Posting this in case someone faces the same issue.